# Map function is not being applied to all expressions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to render genre Name and genre gradient using map function over,genres array.The map function works fine for the genre Name but for genre gradient it returns the same component.

I tried checking on the console. I am  able to see two different colorrs but the final output on the screen is "GenreGradient" component with  same color.

Please help with the same.

Kindlly find below my code.

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import {
  GenreContainer,
  Genre,
  GenreName
} from '../../styles/componentStyles/GenreDetails/genreCommonStyles';

import {
  TheGrandPhilisophers,
  GuidingLights,
  ArchitectsOfFuture,
  MaverickScientists,
  Luminaries,
  MenOfLetters
} from '../../styles/componentStyles/GenreDetails/genreDetails';

import GenreGradient from './GenreGradient';
import GenreFancyItemContext from '../../Context/genreFancyITem/GenreFancyItemContext';

const genres = [
  {
    genreName: 'guidingLights',
    genreGradientColor: '#34e89e'
  },
  {
    genreName: 'luminaries',
    genreGradientColor: '#3b4490'
  }
];

console.log(genres);

const GenreDetails = () => {
  const genreFancyItemContext = useContext(GenreFancyItemContext);

  const { getGenreName } = genreFancyItemContext;

  return (
    <GenreContainer>
      {genres.map(genre => (
        <Genre to={`/genreFancyitems/${genre.genreName}`}>
          <GenreGradient genreColor={`${genre.genreGradientColor}`} />
          <GenreName>{getGenreName(genre.genreName)}</GenreName>
        </Genre>
      ))}
    </GenreContainer>
  );
};

export default GenreDetails;
```

```
import * as React from 'react';

const GenreGradient = props => {
  console.log(props);
  return (
    <svg width={300} height={150} viewBox="0 0 92.704 53.017">
      <defs>
        <radialGradient
          xlinkHref="#prefix__a"
          id="prefix__b"
          cx={-428.286}
          cy={25.74}
          fx={-428.286}
          fy={25.74}
          r={46.352}
          gradientTransform="matrix(-.81297 -1.42269 1.99784 -1.14162 -241.802 -509.53)"
          gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
        />
        <linearGradient id="prefix__a">
          <stop offset={0} stopColor={props.genreColor} stopOpacity={0.808} />
          <stop offset={1} stopColor={props.genreColor} stopOpacity={0} />
        </linearGradient>
      </defs>
      <path
        fill="url(#prefix__b)"
        fillRule="evenodd"
        d="M65.201 70.403h92.604v52.917H65.201z"
        transform="translate(-65.15 -70.353)"
      />
    </svg>
  );
};

export default GenreGradient;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDs are global in the page. 
After render you have two elements with same id. And when you are trying to use it (`xlinkHref="#prefix__a"`, `fill="url(#prefix__b)"`), first element will be used.

You have to use different IDs for different elements. For example, you can use genreName as a prefix for ID.

Comment: Thanks!Aleksandr for your input..Can please help me with  syntax for the id.. I  am getting syntax error

Comment: How are you trying to do it? You have to pass genreName into GenreGradient and use it inside props with id. For example — ```xlinkHref={`#${props.genreName}__a`}```

Comment: "url({`#${props.genreName}__b`})" {`${props.genreName}__b`} Can you please help me with fill URl

Comment: id={`${props.genreName}__a`} {`#${props.genreName}__a`}This is another set of ID i am using

Comment: Seems like you forgot to use backticks — ```fill={`url(#${props.genreName}__b)`}```

Comment: Sorry mate but I am stuck at the syntax..Could youn please help! .. Thanks a lot buddy saved my day!